# What's the difference between df.iloc[:,1:2].values and df.iloc[:,1].values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

When i `used x = dataset.iloc[:,1:2].values` and later on in my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:,1:2].values #look here please
y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
from sklearn.svm import SVR
sv_regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf')
```

so when i used `x = dataset.iloc[:,1].values` instead, i got an error saying

> 'expected 2d array and got 1d array instead'

in the sv_regresso line

The error is in `sv_regressor` line w, that's why i tagged `sklearn`

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that with `dataset.iloc[:,1:2]` you will get a `DataFrame` and with `dataset.iloc[:,-1]` you will get a `Series`. When you use the attribute `values` with a `DataFrame` you get a 2d ndarray and with a `Series` you get a 1d ndarray. Consider the following example:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  2  0
1  1  0  0
2  1  2  1
```

Series:

```
type(df.iloc[:, -1])
# pandas.core.series.Series

df.iloc[:, -1].values.shape
# (3,)
```

DataFrame:

```
type(df.iloc[:, -1:])
# pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

df.iloc[:, -1:].values.shape
# (3, 1)
```

It's a common trick in machine learning to get a target variable as 2d ndarray in one step.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost the same, `dataset.iloc[:,1:2]` gives you a 2-d dataframe (columns from 1 to 2), `dataset.iloc[:,1]` gives you a pandas series (1-d) (from column 1).